# How to read JSON response data with a space in path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to read JSON response data from a Restful API that contains a space in the path. I am trying to accomplish this in JavaScript, but can't seem to get the data to display.

Below is the JSON I am working with:

```
"fields": {
  "census": {...},
  "acs": {
    "meta": {
      "source": "American Community Survey from the US Census Bureau",
      "survey_years": "2014-2018",
      "survey_duration_years": "5"
    },
    "demographics": {
      "Median age": {
        "meta": {
          "table_id": "B01002",
          "universe": "Total population"
        },
        "Total": {
          "value": 32.8,
          "margin_of_error": 0.6
```

As you can see, the Median Age field has a space. The actual data I am trying to obtain is the Median age total value.

Below is my JSON path that isn't working:

```
        let ageDems = await response.data.results[0].fields.demographics.$["Median age"].Total.value;
```

I have also tried to use ['Median Age'], ["Median Age"] and Median+Age and none of those worked either.
Can anyone please assist me in writing the correct path to obtain the data I need?

Comment: Give me a somewhat complete view of the data and I'll show you, but you'll need to provide a starting point. All I need is the `acs` part.

Comment: `const ageDems = response.data.results[0].fields.demographics["Median age"].Total.value;`,  `console.log(ageDems )`

Comment: If after reviewing my answer, you discover the error in your code, please upvote and accept the answer **from Ismail** who first answered your question with the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
await response.data.results[0].fields.demographics["Median age"].Total.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ismail's suggestion does work.

This answer is here just to prove it to you. If this is not working for you as demonstrated below, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the error you see.

```js
const data = {
  "acs": {
    "meta": {
      "source": "American Community Survey from the US Census Bureau",
      "survey_years": "2014-2018",
      "survey_duration_years": "5"
    },
    "demographics": {
      "Median age": {
        "meta": {
          "table_id": "B01002",
          "universe": "Total population"
        },
        "Total": {
          "value": 32.8,
          "margin_of_error": 0.6
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(data.acs.demographics["Median age"].Total.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`demographics` is nested under `acs`:

```js
await response.data.results[0].fields.acs.demographics["Median age"].Total.value
```